# сложить полученные значения input и вывести общую сумму в HTML при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript, функции, input, события, button

Помогите новичку: нужно сложить все "итого" (id="summa") по выбранному товару и при нажатии на кнопку вывести "общую сумму" (id="tot_summ") в HTML. Получилось вывести только значения, но они не суммируются. Нужен код на javascript (jQuery вообще не понимаю). Заранее спасибо

```js
function calkulator() {

  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.pr');
  var sumsTotal = document.querySelectorAll('#summa');
  var sums = document.querySelectorAll('.sum');

  inputs.forEach((item, i) => {
    item.addEventListener('input', () => {
      var x = item.value * Number(sums[i].innerHTML);
      sumsTotal[i].innerHTML = x;
      // console.log(x);

      var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
      for (var button of buttons) {
        button.addEventListener('click', () =>
          document.getElementById('tot_summ').innerHTML += Number.parseInt(x));
        /*console.log("buttons")*/

      };
    });
  });

}
calkulator();
```

```css
body {
  display: inline-block;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  display: inline;
}

.vegetables__list {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-3 vegetables__total">
  <p class="tot"><b>ОБЩАЯ СТОИМОСТЬ: </b><span id="tot_summ">0</span><b> руб.</b></p>
</div>

<div class="col-3 vegetables__list">
  <input id="vegetable" type="checkbox" class="ida" name="veget carrot" value="60" />
  <h2>морковь </h2>
  </input><br><br>
  <p>Цена: <span class="sum">60</span> руб./кг</p>
  <p>Количество: <input type="number" name="quantity" class="pr" min="0" max="50" step="0.1" value="" id="quantity" /><span> кг</span></p>
  <p>Итого: <span id="summa"></span> руб. </p>
  <button type="button" class="btn" id="but">В корзину</button>
</div>

<div class="col-3 vegetables__list">
  <input id="vegetable" type="checkbox" name=" veget beet" class="ida" value="80" />
  <h2>свекла</h2>
  </input><br><br>
  <p>Цена: <span class="sum">80</span> руб./кг</p>
  <p>Количество: <input type="number" name="quantity" class="pr" min="0" max="50" step="0.1" value="" id="quantity" /><span> кг</span></p>
  <p>Итого: <span id="summa"> </span> руб.</p>
  <button type="button" class="btn" id="but">В корзину</button>
</div>

<div class="col-3 vegetables__list">
  <input id="vegetable" type="checkbox" name="veget cabbage" class="ida" value="40" />
  <h2>капуста белокочанная</h2>
  </input><br><br>
  <p>Цена: <span class="sum">40 </span> руб./кг</p>
  <p>Количество: <input type="number" name="quantity" class="pr" min="0" max="50" step="0.1" value="" id="quantity" /><span> кг</span></p>
  <p>Итого: <span id="summa"></span> руб.</p>
  <button type="button" class="btn" id="but">В корзину</button>
</div>
```

Comment: В коде не должно быть повторяющихся id

Comment: Возможно дубликат вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1436342/как-перемножить-значения-input

Comment: это не дубликат - это продолжение ((( в первом вопросе рассчитывалась стоимость конкретного товара, а сейчас нужно эти стоимости вывести в общий итог при нажатии на кнопку. у меня выводится какая-то ерунда и итог не считается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам не нужно оборачивать всё это в функцию, это лишнее. Получали вы не то что вам нужно из-за того, что складывали строку с числом, что в конечном итоге приводило результат к строке. И, пожалуйста, перестаньте пихать в html ненужные id только ради того, чтобы по ним получать элементы в js. Это можно спокойно сделать по классам. А эти ваши id только создают лишний код в html и лишний раз перебивают селекторы в css. Ну и к тому же, как сказали в комментариях, id должен быть уникальным, а они у вас повторяются.

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.pr');
const sumsTotal = document.querySelectorAll('#summa');
const sums = document.querySelectorAll('.sum');
const buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');
const sum = document.getElementById('tot_summ');
let sumTotal = 0;

inputs.forEach((item, i) => {
  item.addEventListener('input', () => {
    sumsTotal[i].innerHTML = item.value * Number(sums[i].innerHTML);
  });
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    sumTotal += Number(sumsTotal[i].innerHTML);
    sum.innerHTML = sumTotal;
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  display: inline-block;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  display: inline;
}

.vegetables__list {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-3 vegetables__total">
  <p class="tot"><b>ОБЩАЯ СТОИМОСТЬ: </b><span id="tot_summ">0</span><b> руб.</b></p>
</div>

<div class="col-3 vegetables__list">
  <input id="vegetable" type="checkbox" class="ida" name="veget carrot" value="60" />
  <h2>морковь </h2>
  </input><br><br>
  <p>Цена: <span class="sum">60</span> руб./кг</p>
  <p>Количество: <input type="number" name="quantity" class="pr" min="0" max="50" step="0.1" value="" id="quantity" /><span> кг</span></p>
  <p>Итого: <span id="summa"></span> руб. </p>
  <button type="button" class="btn" id="but">В корзину</button>
</div>

<div class="col-3 vegetables__list">
  <input id="vegetable" type="checkbox" name=" veget beet" class="ida" value="80" />
  <h2>свекла</h2>
  </input><br><br>
  <p>Цена: <span class="sum">80</span> руб./кг</p>
  <p>Количество: <input type="number" name="quantity" class="pr" min="0" max="50" step="0.1" value="" id="quantity" /><span> кг</span></p>
  <p>Итого: <span id="summa"> </span> руб.</p>
  <button type="button" class="btn" id="but">В корзину</button>
</div>

<div class="col-3 vegetables__list">
  <input id="vegetable" type="checkbox" name="veget cabbage" class="ida" value="40" />
  <h2>капуста белокочанная</h2>
  </input><br><br>
  <p>Цена: <span class="sum">40 </span> руб./кг</p>
  <p>Количество: <input type="number" name="quantity" class="pr" min="0" max="50" step="0.1" value="" id="quantity" /><span> кг</span></p>
  <p>Итого: <span id="summa"></span> руб.</p>
  <button type="button" class="btn" id="but">В корзину</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо Вам, Сергей! Не судите строго - я только учусь. Насчет id поняла